# Image scale by -webkit-transform

Tags: css, animation

I have one img in the body.

```
$(function() {
    var body = $("body"),
    scaled;
    $("img").click(function() {
        if(scaled) {
            body.css("-webkit-transform", "scale3d(1, 1, 1)");     
        } else {
            body.css("-webkit-transition", "-webkit-transform 0.2s ease");     
            body.css("-webkit-transform", "scale3d(8, 8, 1)");     
        }
        scaled = !scaled;
    });
});
```

I'm clicking at image.

Scale to 8x is smooth.
First scale from 8x to 1x is bad (
Second scale from 8x to 1x is smooth.

Click image...

Fiddle for chrome: [example](http://jsfiddle.net/zNDx6/1/)

I can use only -webkit-transform,

how I can may be cache animation...

What to do?

In IE11 - everything OK.
I can't solve problem in Chrome.

Comment: your question is not clear...kinda rewrite what is your problem. Its like you want your animation to be able to appear in, firefox, opera  and IE ?

Comment: Both looks same to me

Answer (score 0):

This is what you're looking for:

```
* {
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0,0,0);
}
```

**[The fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zNDx6/2/)**